# Android AdMob embeding, network and centering problems

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob, centering

I am trying to add admob on my application. What I wanna see is bottom center admob banner but I couldn't do it after 5 hours and looking for help. (yes 5 fraking hours)
I have 2 errors also which make admob doesn't even show up I believe..

one error is "onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)" 
and other one is "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout"

I tried any FILL PARRENT WRAP CONTENT and Gravity.CENTER Combination even which are I didnt write here coz of so many of them. even if It shows up still at left-bottom. 
I need center-bottom...

Many thanks in advance for your help

Here the code and logCAT;

```
Window window = getWindow();
    RelativeLayout adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1xxx6c");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adsLayout.addView(adView);
    window.addContentView(adsLayout,lp2);




I/Ads(4564): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1.5,"slotname":"a1xxx6c","u_w":569,"msid":"ko.tb","simulator":1,"cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.3.1","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"11.android.ko.tb","hl":"en","u_h":320,"u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>
D/dalvikvm(4564): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 80K, 49% free 2820K/5511K, external 17296K/18967K, paused 113ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(4564): Clamp target GC heap from 24.915MB to 24.000MB
D/dalvikvm(4564): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6K, 49% free 2814K/5511K, external 18046K/18967K, paused 48ms
E/ERROR(4564): ERROR IN CODE: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(4564):java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(4564):at ko.tb.KOActivity.EksikSorularWebService(KOActivity.java:1413)
W/System.err(4564):at ko.tb.KOActivity.checkDB(KOActivity.java:457)
W/System.err(4564):at ko.tb.KOActivity.GenelTimeline(KOActivity.java:410)
W/System.err(4564):at ko.tb.KOActivity$1.onTick(KOActivity.java:307)
W/System.err(4564):at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
W/System.err(4564):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(4564):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(4564):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
W/System.err(4564):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(4564):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err(4564):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
W/System.err(4564):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
W/System.err(4564):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/webcore(4564): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
I/Ads(4564): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
D/webviewglue(4564): nativeDestroy view: 0x3903c0
I/Ads(4564): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="14" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|s‌​creenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: Have you enabled internet permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem

```
    com.google.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.ads.AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(com.google.ads.AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

    adView.setPadding(200, 0, 0, 0);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

also I Ignored the error "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout" which I still getting but no effect I believe..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting that exception.  The AdMob implementation looks correct, though I'm not familiar with adding a content view from the window.  Also, are you sure your emulator/device has access to the internet?  Unless it's related to the exception, a network error means internet connectivity issues.  Try hitting your home page on your mobile browser.

As for centering the AdView, try setting the `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` parameter:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
adsLayout.addView(adView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, maybe it will help you. Place your ad into linearLayout or other, and then use it like my code.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reklam);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx");  
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(true);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My Android game was published on the Google's market, but I didn't get any impressions from AdMob. There was no significant changes in the code, or even changes at all that touched AdMob sources and the previous versions of my game were working properly.

As it turned out the problem was elevated during obfuscation process done by proguard. If you're using it to do the mangling of Java's symbols get rid of the `-optimize` directive from your proguard.cfg and put `-dontoptimize` instead.